# why .click() doesn't work on android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Strange situation:

on my `plugins.js` file I have that simple function:

```
 function getFile(id) {
     document.getElementById("fileUploadHidden+" + id).click();
 }
```

It works perfectly on web browsers - even on WindowsPhone, iPhone/iPad.. but not on android. It looks like android browser ignores `.click()` function.

Why? And how to resolve it?

Comment: can you post what you get in the variable `id` and your Html too.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click/38073679#answer-38073679

Answer (score 3):

I think you should add the `touchstart`:

```
var isMobile = {
   Android: function() {
      return /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
   },
   BlackBerry: function() {
      return /BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
   },
   iOS: function() {
      return /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
   },
   Windows: function() {
      return /IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
   },
   any: function() {
      return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows());
   }
};

if(isMobile.any){
   document.getElementById("fileUploadHidden+" + id).trigger('touchstart');
}else{
   document.getElementById("fileUploadHidden+" + id).trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If id name is `fileUploadHidden`

Try

```
$("#fileUploadHidden" + id).click();
```

If id name is `fileUploadHidden+`

Try

```
$("#fileUploadHidden\\+"+id).click();
```

Comment: $('#fileUploadHidden+' + id).click() - missing the #

Comment: @Anton Yes OP told its not working thats why check with jquery

Comment: Both the codes are the same. You don't need to use `#` in javascript.

Comment: Clear your cache? The jQuery version should work no issues across all browsers.

Comment: @SridharR You are also missing the `+` at the end of `fileUploadHidden` and you must escape `+ ` with \\ like this `$("#fileUploadHidden\\+"+id).click();` if you want to use jQuery. But `document.getElementId('id')` is the same as `$('#id')`

Answer (score 0):

I never coded for android browsers, but I research such problems first with 
alerts to see if the element is found by the browser.

try:

alert(document.getElementById("fileUploadHidden+" + id));

and see if it is [object] or null.

Then you can check wether it is the document.getElementById or the click method that makes the problem.

Here are some related topics:

- [Javascript AJAX Click event sometimes not working in Android native browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631597/javascript-ajax-click-event-sometimes-not-working-in-android-native-browser)
- [JavaScript click events not working on Samsung Galaxy SIII on Android 4.0.4 default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522140/javascript-click-events-not-working-on-samsung-galaxy-siii-on-android-4-0-4-defa)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a browser issue.

Try this.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("fileUploadHidden+" + id);
if (elem.onclick) {
   elem.onclick();
} else if (elem.click) {
   elem.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my little experience I solved click/tap problems with a library called zepto.js, basically a light jquery library with support to sreen events
http://zeptojs.com/

the problem is that click and tap is not exactly same and system can handle it in different mode. Zepto had a method tap() that maybe was the solution for you.
you can see gestual methods on
http://zeptojs.com/#modules